# Angular how to handle a nested http response

Tags: json, angular, http

My angular service returns the following type of response:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "id": 1,
  "list": [
     {
        "name": "listName1",
        "id": 1
     },
     {
        "name": "listName2",
        "id": 2
     }
   ]
}
```

This is what the call in the service looks like:

```
fetchX(): Observable<X> {
  return this.http.get<X>(some_url)
}
```

Now, in my component I can access the 'name' and 'id' attribute of the returned object, but for the 'list', which is a list itself, I only get 'undefined'. I'm displaying the list elements in my application (by their name), and they don't actually show up there either (the HTML part for this is definitely correct, this isn't the issue).

```
myX: CustomX
myList: CustomList[]


ngOnInit() {
  this.service.fetchX().subscribe((response) => {
      this.myX = response,
      this.myList = response.list,
      console.log(response.name), //returns 'abc'
      console.log(response.id),   //returns '1'
      console.log(response.list)  //returns 'undefined'})}
```

The entities look like this:

```
export class CustomX {
  name: string
  id: number
  list: CustomList[]
}

class CustomList {
  name: string
  id: number
}
```

What am I missing? I think I may be handling the response in the service incorrectly.

Comment: Check the names in your X interface definition, if they match, they should be mapped automatically - including nested arrays/objects

Comment: @Bertramp thank you so much, that solved the problem. I spent a few hours trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: You should consider using interface instead of classes. In typescript interface are like a contract : every object having the same properties than your interface will be cosidered as this interface.

Comment: @mJehanno That is only true at compile time. Unlike classes, interfaces don't exist at runtime in JS, and i can assign whatever object i desire to that interface